# Drawing circle on existing PDF using itextsharp c#

Tags: c#, itext

I got some troubles drawing circle on an existing pdf, I found a code to add text on existing PDF, I tried to adapt it to draw circle but the result is just a blank page Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

My code:

```
        string oldFile = @"C:\...6166-21.pdf";
        string newFile = @"C:\...NEW.pdf";

        // open the reader
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(oldFile);
        Rectangle size = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1);
        Document document = new Document(size);

        FileStream fs = new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs);
        document.Open();

        // the pdf content
        PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;

        cb.Circle(150f, 150f, 50f);
        cb.SetColorStroke(iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.GREEN);

        // create the new page and add it to the pdf
        PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, 1);
        cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);

        // close the streams and voilá the file should be changed :)
        document.Close();
        fs.Close();
        writer.Close();
        reader.Close();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to add `cb.Stroke();`

Please try like this:

```
cb.SetColorStroke(iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.GREEN);
cb.Circle(150f, 150f, 50f);
cb.Stroke();
```

Comment: For valid PDF do `cb.SetColorStroke` before `cb.Circle`: As soon as path construction has begun, only further path construction operations, clipping path operations or path drawing operations are allowed. (Many viewers will accept your result but later versions may change in that respect.)